# Real time chat in angular 2 and mvc web api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I need to implement real time chat in my project. Please guide me about the best option available.
chat should be one to one and group chat.
I am using angular 2 at the front end while web api 2 with entity framework at the back end.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write your own chat framework you can start using **[`socket.io`](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)**

Since you are from .net background, you can use **[`signalR`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr)** with dot net core

Here is a **[`sample app`](https://github.com/sajeetharan/ng-chat)**

If you don't want to spend much time, you can simply use the following 3rd party services

(i) [`Pusher.com`](https://pusher.com/)

(ii) [`OneSignal`](https://onesignal.com/)

Comment: are these free ? what about signalr ?

Comment: socket.io is free. infact since you want to do with asp.net signalR is a good choice

Comment: did the answer help?